# How does jquery mobile center text select list?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I need to center text in a select list. The only example ive found that achieves this is jQuery Mobile. I dont want to use the framework but now that I know its possible, how do they do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery Mobile hides the input and creates divs to center the text.

Answer (score 0):

Just you find the class of the Select box and give the

```
padding:%px or text-align:Center
```

Comment: Text align center is ignored by iPhone and other browsers. The layout has a liquid width so I cant use a padding value, even a %. Thanks

Comment: i tried my smart phone.. I find the css class through firebug of the select box and give the padding_left or text-align so its work fine..

Comment: Text aligned center works in firefox but not chrom or an iphone http://jsfiddle.net/jamesbrighton/yQSYS/

Comment: Padding left wont work as my layout is liquid. The only solution I can this of is to use JavaScript to calculate what padding is needed to center the text and apply it dynamically.

Comment: I think jQuery Mobile hides the input and creates divs to center the text. This seems like quite a long winded work around for me.